# How to sort list of dictionaries by value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
dictionary[pattern_key] = {"key": index_key, "document": index_source, "startPos":index_start, "endPos": index_end}
```

This is an extract of my list of dictionaries

```
{
'AGACAATCTC': {'startPos': '174', 'document': 'source-document01012.txt', 'endPos': '183', 'key': 'AGACAATCTC'}, 
'GGTCAGACAA': {'startPos': '18', 'document': 'source-document01012.txt', 'endPos': '27', 'key': 'GGTCAGACAA'}, 
'TAGATGAAGT': {'startPos': '102', 'document': 'source-document01012.txt', 'endPos': '111', 'key': 'TAGATGAAGT'}
}
```

How can i sort that by **document** and then by **startPos** ?

i tried something like this but does not work

`sorted_dict = sorted(dictionary, key=itemgetter(pattern_key[document]))`

script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

dictionary = {};

for pattern in sys.stdin:

    if "," in pattern:
        pattern_key, pattern_source, pattern_start, pattern_end = pattern.strip().split(",")
        index_file =  open('index.txt', 'r')

        for line in index_file:
            if "," in line:
                index_key, index_source, index_start, index_end = line.strip().split(",")
                if pattern_key == index_key:
                    dictionary[pattern_key] = {"document": index_source, "startPos":index_start, "endPos": index_end}

sorted(dictionary.items(), key = lambda x: (x[1]['document'], int(x[1]['startPos'])))

for k, v in dictionary.items():
    print (k, '-->', v)
```

Comment: For output, do you want the entire dict values, or just the keynames? 
['AGACAATCTC', 'TAGATGAAGT'] like that?

Comment: i need the entire output sorted by document and then startPos...

Comment: Sorted does NOT update the dictionary to have sorted values. You need to use the list of (<key>, <dict-val>) tuple returned by sorted() command. If you convert list of tuples to dictionary and then use it, it may again disturb the sorted order.

Comment: I don't see a list of dict. but instead a dict. of dict. or am I missing something here?

Comment: If you want a dictionary to be sorted, you'll need to use `collections.OrderedDict`. Regular dictionaries do not guarantee the order of the keys.

Comment: Also, `sorted` does not edit an object in place, it returns a new object. (And per my previous comment, it's not possible to sort a regular dictionary in place.)

Comment: thank you for your input @JaredGoguen !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the entries in the inner dictionary as keys for `sorted`:

```
sorted(dictionary.items(), key = lambda x: (x[1]['document'], int(x[1]['startPos'])))
```

A tuple key will be sorted first by the 0th element, then 1st, and so on.

Note that this produces a list of tuples, where each tuple is `(str, dict)`.

EDIT:
In your context, the correct implementation is the following:

```
sorted_values = sorted(dictionary.items(), key = lambda x: (x[1]['document'], int(x[1]['startPos'])))

for k, v in sorted_values:
    print (k, '-->', v)
```

Comment: Running this on your sample data returns: `('GGTCAGACAA', {'document': 'source-document01012.txt', 'endPos': '27', 'startPos': '18', 'key': 'GGTCAGACAA'})
('TAGATGAAGT', {'document': 'source-document01012.txt', 'endPos': '111', 'startPos': '102', 'key': 'TAGATGAAGT'})
('AGACAATCTC', {'document': 'source-document01012.txt', 'endPos': '183', 'startPos': '174', 'key': 'AGACAATCTC'})`. This is sorted by `document` and `startPos`.

Comment: Can you give an example, for what value it did not sort using 'startPos'? Because I tried similar approach and it worked for me.

Comment: hmm weird, it gives me a randomized output? `('AAAGCTTACA', '-->', {'startPos': '132', 'document': 'source-document01012.txt', 'endPos': '141'})
('GGAGAAATCT', '-->', {'startPos': '78', 'document': 'source-document01012.txt', 'endPos': '87'})
('TCGGGAGCAA', '-->', {'startPos': '216', 'document': 'source-document01012.txt', 'endPos': '225'})
('CGGTTTATGT', '-->', {'startPos': '204', 'document': 'source-document01012.txt', 'endPos': '213'})
('TCACGTAGGA', '-->', {'startPos': '234', 'document': 'source-document01012.txt', 'endPos': '243'})` i removed "key" just for clarity, do not mind the "-->"

Comment: No the sort works. Are you sure everything else is in place and proper?

Comment: will post my whole script

Comment: You need to assign the value of the sorted dictionary to something, and then print those values, not the values of the original dictionary. Dictionaries are unordered, and therefore cannot be sorted in place. I'll make an edit to my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Make your sorting based on your desired criteria then create a new [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the sorted list, since `dict` cannot keep the sorting by it's nature:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>>
>>> d = {'AGACAATCTC': {'endPos': '183', 'document': 'source-document01010.txt', 'key': 'AGACAATCTC', 'startPos': '174'}, 'GGTCAGACAA': {'endPos': '27', 'document': 'source-document01010.txt', 'key': 'GGTCAGACAA', 'startPos': '18'}, 'TAGATGAAGT': {'endPos': '111', 'document': 'source-document01011.txt', 'key': 'TAGATGAAGT', 'startPos': '102'}}
>>> 
>>> d_ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t:(t[1]['document'], int(t[1]['startPos']))))
>>> 
>>> d_ordered
OrderedDict([('GGTCAGACAA', {'endPos': '27', 'document': 'source-document01010.txt', 'key': 'GGTCAGACAA', 'startPos': '18'}), ('AGACAATCTC', {'endPos': '183', 'document': 'source-document01010.txt', 'key': 'AGACAATCTC', 'startPos': '174'}), ('TAGATGAAGT', {'endPos': '111', 'document': 'source-document01011.txt', 'key': 'TAGATGAAGT', 'startPos': '102'})])
```